# French equivalent for "Cloud Cuckoo Land"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, proverbes

Is there a French equivalent to the English phrase "Cloud Cuckoo Land"?  This noun phrase is used to describe an imaginary place that a person is in when they the speaker believes that they're hoping for that which is unattainable, or practising wishful thinking.  An example would be:

> I've invented a great new product!
>   *You're living in Cloud Cuckoo Land if you think that is going to save the company from bankruptcy.*

Comment: [tvtropes: Cloud Cuckoo Lander](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CloudCuckooLander)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a non official context, you can translate it with

> le pays des Bisounours

where “[Bisounours](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisounours)” (apparently known in the US as [Care Bears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Care_Bears)) were popular characters of a children TV program where everybody were nice and everything had happy endings.

[image: Bisounours]

If you seek a little more “sarcastic” reference, you can use a title of a [Jean Yanne movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069397/combined):

> Tout le monde il est beau, tout le monde il est gentil.

Comment: Cédric, you scooped me by 27 seconds, so I merged my answer with yours above (well, the Wikipedia link and the image, basically). I hope you don't mind…

Comment: @F'x no problem, I was just looking for an english version ;)

Comment: I'd think using "bisonours" really depends of the context. Not everyone will grasp what you mean.

Answer (score 18):

Officiellement, [Coucouville-les-nuées](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Oiseaux_%28Aristophane%29) est la traduction de l'original *Νεφελοκοκκυγία* d'Aristophane.

Mais je doute fort que grand-monde la comprenne. Opte pour les bisounours, ou éventuellement l'expression *sur un petit nuage* ou *sur son petit nuage* ou peut-être même *dans les nuages*.

Ou encore, peut-être plus habituel, *se faire des (douces) illusions* :

> J'ai inventé un produit génial!
>   Tu te fais des douces illusions si tu crois que ça va empêcher la faillite de l'entreprise.

Et dans ce cas, à vrai dire, l'expression n'est même pas nécessaire pour peu qu'on ajoute un peu d'emphase :

> Si tu crois que ça va empêcher la faillite de l'entreprise !

Il y a encore le classique *tu te fourres le doigt dans l'œil*, et notons aussi qu'on peut proposer à quelqu'un qui se trouverait sur son nuage de *redescendre sur terre* :

> J'ai inventé un produit génial!
>   Redescends sur terre, ce n'est pas ça qui va empêcher la faillite de l'entreprise.

Comment: +1 pour la mention d'Aristophane.

Comment: *Mais où il va chercher ça…* Joli. Maintenant, pour placer Coucouville dans une conversation, il faut peut-être déjà y habiter…

Answer (score 9):

In French, something that will be understood by everyone and don't depend on your cultural background:

> — Descends de ton nuage.

(climb off your cloud)

with some variants:

> — Tu vis sur un nuage.
>
> — Tu vis dans un monde imaginaire.

Answer (score 6):

I've also heard (and I'm using) other possibilities like:

- *C'est [pas] le monde de Oui-Oui* (french version of [Noddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noddy_%28character%29))
- *C'est [pas] Disneyland* (no reference needed for this one I think)

I particularly like the last one and when I hear it, the (excellent) movie *[Le goût des autres](http://www.imdb.fr/title/tt0216787/)* comes to my mind with the following quote:

> - Mais non, il est pas moche le monde, Madame Castella... Il est comme il est, faut faire avec...
>   - Non ! Moi j'ai pas envie de faire avec ! C'est trop dégoûtant, c'est trop horrible, ça m'intéresse pas.
>   - Ben faut vivre à Disneyland...

*Le monde des Bisounours* works quite fine also.

Answer (score 2):

Tu vis dans la Lune marche aussi depuis Cyrano de Bergerac au moins :D

Answer (score 0):

For the particular expression as given in the question you could possibly translate by "Si tu crois que X va sauver la société t'as vraiment perdu la boule".
I like that "perdre la boule" expression, and apparently it comes from "losing a sense of direction", but it doesn't use the English expression's notion of "nonsense land", "Noddy land" or, even less, Aristophanes' Νεφελοκοκκυγία.
I wonder whether this is the only example where demotic English has assimilated a classical allusion where French simply hasn't got any equivalent assimilation?